# How to use context properties in an Activity diagram in UML?

Tags: uml

Considering the following class diagram:

[image]

The class `System` is active and its behaviour is to continuously

- call `filter` on `PressureSensorFilter` passing
  `PressureSensor.Pressure` as argument
- call `Display.show` passing the output param of
  `PressureSensorFilter.filter` as argument

I would like to model the behaviour of `System` through an `ActivityDiagram`.

The main challenge in doing this is accessing the property `PressureSensor` of `System`.
After reading the UML 2.5 specification, I believe that the only way to do this is to use `ReadSelfAction`(pag 457 UML 2.5 spec) and `ReadStructuralFeatureAction` (pag 466 UML 2.5 spec) as depicted by the following Activity diagram:

[image]

where

- `ReadSelfAction` gives as output a current Instance of `System`.
- `ReadPressureSensorFe..` is a `REadStructuralFeatureAction` that reads the property `PressureSensor` of the object give at its input pin which in this case is the current Instance of System.
- `CallBesselFilter.filter Action` and `CallDisplay.show Action` are two `CallOperationAction`(s) that call `PressureSensorFilter.filter` and `Display.show` respectively.

The issue with this is that is very convoluted and unclear. 
Is there any less convoluted and more clear way to describe the behaviour of System through an Activity diagram?

Answer (score 0):

The `ReadSelfAction` as extra action is superfluous. You can reduce the control flow like this:

[image]

The pressure is read by the filter from the `Pressure` class' property. The filtered output is sent to `Display` and looping....

You should look into SysML. It's designed to cope with exactly that kind of problems you deal with.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what detail you would like to provide in your activity diagram. The diagram you provide is correct. By the way, its level of details could be directly used to generate code. If you would like to describe behavior more abstract, do not use actions like read structural feature etc. But in your example, it is very good and precised way of description.